# Why Regex.Ismatch return fail

Tags: c#, regex, string

I had used Regex string:

```
versionPattern = @"^\d+(.\d+){3}$"
```

to check format of string with 4 number have hyphen is `.`

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx or x.x.x.x ...
```

But it return true with string:

```
1.0.0.123
```

and return false with string:

```
1.0.0.4
```

My code for this:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(svnShopLoorTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString(), versionPattern))
{
     //MessageBox.Show("OK");
}
else
{
     //MessageBox.Show("Should be: x.x.x.x");
     s += "\r\nProgram " + svnShopLoorTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString() + " of SHOPFLOOR has wrong version format: "
                        + svnShopLoorTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString() + " should be formated as: " + "x.x.x.x";
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

When `svnShopLoorTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString()` is `1.0.0.123` it's ok, not display `s`. But when `svnShopLoorTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString()` is `1.0.0.4`, it's display log in console:

> Program SetupSheet of SHOPFLOOR has wrong version format: 1.0.0.4
>   should be formated as: x.x.x.x

I don't know why this problem occur. Please help me to explain and solve this. Appreciate any help!

Comment: can't reproduce https://regex101.com/r/nC0wV7/1 , maybe try adding a `m` modifer `@"(?m)regex"`

Comment: It returns **true** for both cases, although I would escape the literal `.` for both good practice and to make sure it's validating an actual dot (otherwise it means any character - except newline).

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I follow Regex format from [MDSN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @hwnd: could you please explain more deeply?

Comment: your regex is correct. can you add code where it's not working?

Comment: @Backs: I had update my code, bro

Comment: https://ideone.com/D1i1CS

Comment: If you put a backslash before the dot, then your problem was the dot, meaning any character. You don't want that. It shouldn't fail the regex, though I guess it's possible that the dot would eat digits too early and cause there to be none for the remaining groups.

Comment: do you have check any blank before or after `1.0.0.4` ,if so ,you can remove `^$` and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild-guess and assume that you have some white-space before or after invalidating your regex.

Your regular expression is valid when that line contains that and only that pattern.

Make sure you do not have any white-space preceding or following "1.0.0.4", or modify your regex to be less strict:

```
versionPattern = @"\d+(.\d+){3}"
```

Or to handle whitespace:

```
versionPattern = @"^\s*\d+(.\d+){3}\s*$"
```

Also you should put a backslash ("\") before the dot ("."), as the dot matches any character in regex.

Meaning this:

```
 ^\d+(.\d+){3}$
```

Would also match this:

```
1a2b3c4
```

But this would not:

```
^\d+(\.\d+){3}$
```

It would only work if the intervening characters were actual dots.

Edit: Now that I see your code I realize that you can also probably just get a away with a Trim, assuming I'm not wrong.

```
svnShopLoorTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString().Trim()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, bro. You saved my day. Problem is solved!